# SQL BETWEEN AND operation on date is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is the SQL query that I'm trying to execute:

```
select *,count(dummy) over(partition by dummy) as total_count 
from aaca711a5e78441cdbf062f1d630ee261 
WHERE (max_timestamp BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2018-01-01') 
ORDER BY max_timestamp DESC
```

As far as I know in a BETWEEN AND operation, both values are inclusive. Here, this query is unable to fetch records corresponding to 2018-01-01.

I changed the query to this:

```
select *,count(dummy) over(partition by dummy) as total_count 
from aaca711a5e78441cdbf062f1d630ee261 
WHERE (max_timestamp >= '2017-01-01' AND max_timestamp <= '2018-01-01') 
ORDER BY max_timestamp DESC
```

Still, it's not working.
Then I tried this:

```
select *,count(dummy) over(partition by dummy) as total_count 
from aaca711a5e78441cdbf062f1d630ee261 
WHERE (max_timestamp >= '2017-01-01' AND max_timestamp <= '2018-01-02') 
ORDER BY max_timestamp DESC
```

It's able to fetch records related to 2018-01-01.

What could be the reason for this? and how can I fix this? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: MySQL doesnt support windows functions like `over(partition by )` so ive removed the MySQL tag...

Comment: Remember that `2018-01-01` means `2018-01-01 00:00:00`. Are the values you're searching for really on or before `2018-01-01 00:00:00`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with Spark.

Please refer to this link for more info:  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-10837

I've fixed this issue by using the date_add function provided by spark.
so the last date was changed to **date_add(endDate, 1)** so that we'll get all the values including those corresponding to the last date.

Answer (score 2):

This is your query:

```
select *, count(dummy) over (partition by dummy) as total_count
from aaca711a5e78441cdbf062f1d630ee261
where max_timestamp BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2018-01-01'
order by max_timestamp DESC;
```

Simply don't use `between` with date times.  Use explicit logic:

```
select *, count(dummy) over (partition by dummy) as total_count
from aaca711a5e78441cdbf062f1d630ee261
where max_timestamp >= '2017-01-01' and
      max_timestamp < '2018-01-02'  --> notice this is one day later
order by max_timestamp DESC;
```

The problem is that you have a time component on the date.

Aaron Bertrand explains this very well in his blog [What do `BETWEEN` and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) (I am amused by the title, given that `BETWEEN` definitely does exist, but there is more controversy about the existence of the devil.)

Comment: The date values that I'm dealing with are dynamic in nature. so how can I pick one day later so that this logic would work?

Comment: You can use `dateadd(day, 1, '2018-01-01')`.

Comment: You could change your where clause to `where datediff(d, max_timestamp, '2017-01-01') <= 0 and datediff(d, max_timestamp, '2018-01-01') >= 0`

Comment: @Skippy . . . And if he does that, then SQL Server will not use indexes for the query.